# How to optimise this select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, optimization, sql-server-2008-r2

The below statement is taking almost 2 minutes to execute, when a  slightly different select statement using the same tables and views with the same results is taking half that:

```
SELECT
@NEW_CAREER_NUMBER = MAX(a.[career number])
FROM selecthr20.employee.[career history] a 
    INNER JOIN selecthr20.Employee.[Current Appointments As At Evaluation Date] b
        ON a.[appointment number] = b.[appointment number]  
    INNER JOIN Employee.[BSK Changes in Selected Period] c
        ON a.[career number] = c.[primary key number]
    INNER JOIN selecthr20.employee.[career history extra detail] d
        ON a.[career number] = d.[career number]
            AND c.[primary key number] = d.[career number]
where c.[primary key name] = 'Career Number'
and c.[audit date] < (Select max([audit date]) from Employee.[BSK Changes in Selected Period] where [primary key number] = @LATEST_CAREER_NUMBER)
and b.[person number] = @PERSON_ID
```

'[BSK changes in Selected Period] c' is a view, the rest are tables.

Comment: You're joining to the view and selecting from it again in your `WHERE` clause, so that could be altered. Beyond that, hard to add much without knowing what the view is made of or what indices you have in place.

Comment: This is a really broad question... not knowing what indexes are there, etc. is going to make this nearly impossible to answer.

Comment: This is a question better asked at [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @davejal Good point, you should vote to close (off topic > belongs on another site) and it will be closed here and opened there.

Comment: Had already done that, not sure if the OP get's the notification to move or not

Comment: @davejal Oh odd, I voted to close but didn't see that anyone else had.

Comment: @JeffreyVanLaethem As broad as it is I saw some potential problems

Answer (score -1):

You had a redundant condition on the d join
Give this a try

```
SELECT
@NEW_CAREER_NUMBER = MAX(a.[career number])
FROM selecthr20.employee.[career history] a 
JOIN selecthr20.Employee.[Current Appointments As At Evaluation Date] b
      ON b.[appointment number] = a.[appointment number] 
     and b.[person number]      = @PERSON_ID  
JOIN selecthr20.employee.[career history extra detail] d
      ON d.[career number] = a.[career number] 
JOIN Employee.[BSK Changes in Selected Period] c
      ON c.[primary key number] = a.[career number] 
     and c.[primary key name]   = 'Career Number'
     and c.[audit date] < ( Select max([audit date])   
                              from Employee.[BSK Changes in Selected Period]
                             where [primary key number] = @LATEST_CAREER_NUMBER );
```

Naturally put an index on the join conditions

And if you have a loop on the c join then use a variable for audit date
I would just do this - there is very little down side

```
declare @auditdate DateTime = ( Select max([audit date]) 
                                  from Employee.[BSK Changes in Selected Period] 
                                 where [primary key number] = @LATEST_CAREER_NUMBER );

... 

and c.[audit date] < @auditdate
```